# Are the ip addresses automatically cached in the recursive DNS when it is returned from the authoritative DNS?

Tags: caching, dns

It is said that the recursive DNS refers to its cache first before performing recursive search on the authoritative DNS. So, I wanted to know how is the DNS caching done. Is it automatic or if no, what happens? How is the DNS record cached?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are running a DNS server, then the caching is being done by your client or and LDNS. Your system runs something called a resolver (set of libraries in linux, DNS client service on windows) whose job it is to take names and turn them into IP address, hopefully following the TTL of the returned records. Additionally, browsers and other applications may also add their own level of caching, often *not* adhering to the TTL returned for the record.

Additionally, your machine will point to another server, either locally or your ISP's, that is your LDNS (local DNS). This is a configuration that's required for proper functioning because it must be specified by IP address, either manually entered or obtained via a mechanism like DHCP.